Restart keyboard service Ubuntu 22.04 due to unresponsive keys
I want to restart the keyboard service on Ubuntu where I have an issue with some keys not working and I know for a fact it is not a hardware issue as it works well when I live boot with Linux mint. What is the way to restart the keyboard service or any other fix for this issue? It is simply impossible to productively code or write with so many keys unresponsive
